# MySQL Node.js module: Unable to create connection pool. Error: Access denied for user

Tags: mysql, node.js, connection-pooling

I am trying to create a connection pool using:

```
  mysql.createPool(dbConnOptions)
```

My dbConnOptions object is:

```
                var dbConnOptions = {
                    host: '192.168.5.11',
                    port:  3306, 
                    user: 'johnDoe', 
                    connectionLimit: 10,
                    charset: "utf8mb4",
                    database: 'myDatabase', 
                    password: 'myPassword',
                    multipleStatements: true
                };
```

I am on a Ubuntu server with /etc/hostname having an entry set to 'myHostname'
I have created a MySql user as

```
         create user 'johnDoe'@'localhost' identified by 'myPassword';
         grant all privileges on myDatabase.* to 'johnDoe'@'localhost';
```

The following error is reported:

```
  Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'johnDoe'@'myHostname' (using password: YES)
```

So I tried the following:

```
 grant all privileges on myDatabase.* to 'johnDoe'@'%';
```

That was rejected with this error:

```
ERROR 1133 (42000): Can't find any matching row in the user table
```

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated. It has been frustrating.

Comment: You have created a user `johndoe@localhost` but you try to access the db with `johndoe@myhost`  and there is no user `johndoe@%` so you can't grant any privileges to that user. `johndoe@host1` and `johndoe@host2` are two totally different users (eventhough they may share the same username) with different priviledges.

Comment: @derpirscher I realized your obvious conclusion but if I create a user johnDoe@myhostname and grant permissions and then later if the entry in /etc/hostname changes, I will have to run another SQL script to grant privileges. I thought that 'localhost' is meant to handle this situation no matter what the host is named.

Comment: then you should use `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` as host ... Because if you are using a custom hostname or the actual IP address, you are not connecting via the loopback device and thus, are not identified as `@localhost`

Comment: @derpirscher That did it. I have another problem elsewhere. Not sure if it is related to this issue. Will try and comment later. In the meanwhile, can you submit yoiur comment as an answer? I will accept it as it resolved my main question and certainly was informative (and will be to others).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created a user `johndoe@localhost` but you try to access the db with `johndoe@myhost` and there is no user `johndoe@%` so you can't grant any privileges to that user.

`johndoe@host1` and `johndoe@host2` are two totally different users (eventhough they may share the same username) with different priviledges.

And if you want to use the privileges for `@localhost` you should use 127.0.0.1 or localhost as host ... Because if you are using a custom hostname or the actual IP address, you are not connecting via the loopback device and thus, are not identified as @localhost